# Laravel Nova set global DateTime format

Tags: laravel-nova

Is there a way to set formatting on a global level for Laravel Nova?

Currently I have to do something like this all over the place:

`DateTime::make('Created At')->sortable()->format('D-M-yyyy H:m'),`

Preferably I would just want all `DateTime` instances to be formatted like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest extending the default `DateTime` field to `App\Nova\Fields\DateTime` and you can have more control on how to define the default for each project.

https://crynobone.com/extending-default-fields-on-laravel-nova/

Answer (score 0):

For Nova 4 users; you can use my (MIT licensed) package [wdelfuego/nova-datetime](https://github.com/wdelfuego/nova-datetime) to add support for a configurable global DateTime format to your fields.